# Compare two arrays and find the differences

Tags: php, arrays, difference

I have an array that contains several names of files of a folder.

If new files are added to that folder I want to get their names.

I thought it would be a good idea to compare the files to the array and create a new array with `array_diff`.

I've ended up with something like:

```
$container = array {"one","two","three"};
$allfiles = array {};

foreach(glob('./images/*.*') as $filename){
     array_push($allfiles,$filename);
 }

$newitems = array_diff($allfiles,$container);
```

Is this right? Is this the way you would do it?

How can I filter for file with a determined extention only to be included in `$allfiles`?

Comment: For now I see that you've ended with code which will not even be parsed. If something is about "is it correct" - then answer is - "test that"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you didn't try to parse the code, because you have syntax error, and you don't know it, by the way, you can change :

```
$container = array {"one","two","three"};
$allfiles = array {};
```

to

```
$container = array("one","two","three");
$allfiles = array();
```